# How to remove elements from vector given another vector of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I have two vectors

```
vector<int> vint;
vector<vector<int>::iterator> viter;
```

What is the best way to remove all elements in `vint` whose iterators are present in `viter`. Currently, I workaround temporarily moving to a `list`

Edit: (Some more background)

This is my current code. I wish I could avoid moving to list and back to vector

```
void foo(std::vector<Blah>& bvec)
{
  std::list<Blah> blist;
  std::move(bvec.begin(), bvec.end(), std::back_inserter(blist));
  bvec.clear();
  std::vector<std::list<Blah>::iterator> selectedElements;
  { 
     //Critical section which holds a mutex. Should be as fast as possible
     for(auto it = blist.begin(), it_end= blist.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
     {
        if(shouldElementBeRemoved(*it))
           selectedElements.push_back(it);
     }
  }
  for(auto& it: selectedElements)
  {
     if(shouldElementReallyBeRemoved(*it))
        blist.erase(it);
  }
  std::move(blist.begin(), blist.end(), std::back_inserter(bvec));
}
```

Could be simplified without list if I can remove directly from vector.

```
void foo(std::vector<Blah>& bvec)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<Blah>::iterator> selectedElements;
  { 
     //Critical section which holds a mutex. Should be as fast as possible
     for(auto it = bvec.begin(), it_end= bvec.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
     {
        if(shouldElementBeRemoved(*it))
           selectedElements.push_back(it);
     }
  }
  for(auto& it: selectedElements)
  {
     if(shouldElementReallyBeRemoved(*it))
        // bvect.erase(it);              //Not safe!
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "all elements in `vint` whose iterators are present in `viter`"

Comment: Were these iterators actually collected from `vint`? Why do you have to temporarily copying them to a `list`? I don't understand this. Doesn't a simple (reverse) loop and`std::vector::erase()` called on `vint` work for you?

Comment: If the iterators in the second vector are pointing to vint, you cannot use erase because you are going to invalidate the iterators. However, if the iterators are pointing to another vector erase will do the job

Comment: You can call `erase()` on `vint` with iterators from `vint` but you have to be careful.  `erase()` invalidates all iterators after it so you have to erase from the back forward

Comment: Would work a lot better if you had indices instead of iterators. Then you could sort them and remove the bigger ones first.

Comment: What NathanOliver said also assumes that iterators in `viter` always point to elements in `vint` that succeed those pointed to by preceding iterators in `viter`. Why aren't you dealing with indices or `int`s instead of iterators? This seems really error prone.

Comment: This is a great question! Don't know why the down vote. @Praetorian I don't think working with indices would help much because when you remove an element all the indices above that index shift. Although I suspect indices do leave you in a slightly better position to find a solution (other than NathanOliver solution that requires a reverse sorted vector)..

Comment: @Borgleader Random access iterators can be sorted too if they all point into the same container.

Comment: One method that could work in some situations is to iterate through your iterators using them to mark the vector elements as 'deleted' and then iterate through your vector deleting the marked elements. For an `int` vector that would require a special value that is otherwise unused like `0` or '-1'. For user defined types you could add a 'deleted' field or use an existing field with an otherwise unused value.

Comment: @T.C. Indices won't be invalidated by a resize, iterators will. I wasn't saying indices were better because they could be sorted. I was saying it was a better choice, and then explaining how it could be done using them.

Comment: Yes. I missed that first. corrected now

Comment: @Galik. No. it is protecting something else not shown in above code. Both `blist` and `bvec` are local

Comment: I would probably consider adding a `deleted` field to `class Blah` and set that to `true` in the critical section if you don't want to erase them directly. But I am not sure how much that would really save you if the vectors are relatively short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your second snippet with a small modification - instead of iterating over `selectedElements` in the forward direction, go backwards. Then the call to `bvec.erase` will never invalidate any iterators that remain in `selectedElements`.

```
void foo(std::vector<Blah>& bvec)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<Blah>::iterator> selectedElements;
  selectedElements.reserve(bvec.size());  // avoid growing the vector while you hold a mutex lock

  { 
     //Critical section which holds a mutex. Should be as fast as possible
     for(auto it = bvec.begin(), it_end= bvec.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
     {
        if(shouldElementBeRemoved(*it))
           selectedElements.push_back(it);
     }
  }
  for(auto first = selectedElements.rbegin(),
           last  = selectedElements.rend();
           first != last;
           ++first)
  {
      if(shouldElementReallyBeRemoved(**first)) 
        bvec.erase(*first);
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfc5307f1ae17eeb)

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to do the right thing for me:

```
#include <algorithm>

  for (auto current = vint.end();
       current >= vint.begin();) {
    current--;
    if (any_of(
          viter.begin(),
          viter.end(),
          [current](std::vector<int>::iterator it) {
            return current == it;
          })) {
      vint.erase(current);
    }
  }
```

Using `any_of` allows the iterator vector to be unsorted.

Comment: +1 straightforward and simple. Good for small vectors. Not good for big ones as changes complexity to O(N^2)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would be appropriate for your situation:

```
struct Blah
{
    bool deleted = false; // add a special field
    // other data
};

void foo(std::vector<Blah>& bvec)
{
    {
        //Critical section which holds a mutex. Should be as fast as possible
        // mark them quickly
        for(auto& b: bvec)
            if(shouldElementBeRemoved(b))
                b.deleted = true;
    }

    // remove them slowly
    for(auto i = bvec.begin(); i != bvec.end();)
    {
        if(i->deleted && shouldElementReallyBeRemoved(*i))
            i = bvec.erase(i);
        else
        {
            i->deleted = false;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```